# format ip in a string using bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a string like this (ics dhcp config):

```
host ws_172.16.0.55 { hardware ethernet 52:54:00:5c:21:19;  fixed-address 172.16.0.55;  option host-name "ws_172.16.0.55"; }
```

I need to format hostnames (eg ws_172.16.0.55) to look like this:

```
ws_172.016.000.055
```

So all octets in ip addresses have three digits, where all blank digits filled with zeroes.
The trick is that string has also a real ip assined to a mac and it has to look normal.

How can i do it using bash/sed/awk?

What i fount in internet

```
sed -r 's/^|\./&00/g; s/0*([0-9]{3})/\1/g'
```

But it changes all ip addresss and adds two zeroes at the begining of the line:

```
00host ws_172.016.000.055   { hardware ethernet 52:54:00:5c:21:19;  fixed-address 172.016.000.055;  option host-name "ws_172.016.000.055"; }
```

Edited:
There are two fields in the line (second one hidden by scroller), so a took 
tripleee's answer and made a pipe:

```
do awk '/^host/ { n = split($2, h, /[_.]/); o = h[1]; sep= "_"; for (i=2; i<=n; sep=".") o = o sprintf("%s%03i", sep, h[i++]); $2 = o }1' | awk '/^host/ { n = split($11, h, /[_.]/); o = h[1]; sep= "_"; for (i=2; i<=n; sep=".") o = o sprintf("%s%03i", sep, h[i++]); $11 = o "\";"}1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the host name is always the second field on a line which starts with `host`, and always contains exactly one underscore,

```
awk '/^host/ { n = split($2, h, /[_.]/);
        o = h[1]; sep= "_";
        for (i=2; i<=n; sep=".") o = o sprintf("%s%03i", sep, h[i++]);
        $2 = o }1' file
```

We split the second field into the array `h`, and pick out the parts which need to be reformatted, and successively join them back into the string `o`.  Before printing, we assign the result back over the original value of `$2`.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` command allows formatting using printf format strings:

```
printf "%03d" 16
```

outputs

```
016
```

You can likely split all of your input and use a single format specifier to output the canonical representation. I believe the printf command is builtin to bash since long enough ago that it should be available everywhere, but I may be wrong. If not, awk also provides printf functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick trial. Make use of it if you find it useful.

```
echo "host ws_172.16.0.55 { hardware ethernet 52:54:00:5c:21:19;  fixed-address 172.16.0.55;  option host-name "ws_172.16.0.55"; }" | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F "_" '{print $2}'|awk -F "." '{pr="";for(col=1; col<=NF; col++) {if(length($col)==1) pr= pr "00"$col; else if(length($col)==2) pr= pr "0"$col; else pr= pr""$col; if(col!=NF) pr = pr"."}; print pr}'
```

For the given input

```
host ws_172.16.0.55 { hardware ethernet 52:54:00:5c:21:19;  fixed-address 172.16.0.55;  option host-name "ws_172.16.0.55"; }
```

The output of the above expression will be

```
172.016.000.055
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution with sed would be

```
echo 'host ws_172.16.0.55 { hardware ethernet 52:54:00:5c:21:19;  fixed-address 172.16.0.55;  option host-name "ws_172.16.0.55"; }'|sed -r 's/(ws_| )(172\.)([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)/\1\2NEW.NEW2/g'
```

Output

```
host ws_172.NEW.NEW2.55 { hardware ethernet 52:54:00:5c:21:19;  fixed-address 172.NEW.NEW2.55;  option host-name "ws_172.NEW.NEW2.55"; }
```

where NEW, NEW2 would be a new string.

See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html for learning sed.